# Rails Form_tag syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get an error when I run this code. I want to make a button that redirects to an action from pages_controller.

Submultimi.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => '/pages_controller', :action => 'calculeaza'}, :method => "post") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :field1 %>
<%= submit_tag "Button" %>
<% end %>
```

pages_controller.rb

```
def Submultimi
end
def Combinari
end
def Permutari
end
def calculeaza
puts "YAY"
redirect_to '/combinari' 
end
```

Error message: No route matches {:action=>"calculeaza", :controller=>"pages_controller"}

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get '/submultimi' => 'pages#Submultimi'
 get '/combinari' => 'pages#Combinari' 
get '/permutari' => 'pages#Permutari'
end
```

Comment: Edit your post and add the error message you get.

Comment: done, I added the error to the question

Comment: Also add your routes

Comment: ok, done, added the routes.rb file

Comment: In your routes and controller, method names must be lowercase. In addition you used get in routes and post in the form. Finally, there's no calculeaza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Pablo said, remove the / from your controller name.

Your error message says there is no route defined. That means you haven't correctly told rails what to do with your form's post request; it's trying a route that doesn't exist.

You've got a few things going wrong. Your action names are capitalized in routes.rb, but your method names (at least the one you've linked) is not. They're case sensitive, convention is all lowercase. Also, you don't have a route defined for calculeaza. You need one, in routes.rb add (something like, I haven't tested any of this):

`post '/calculeaza/' to 'pages#calculeaza'`

If you want to see your currently defined routes, run `rails routes` in a terminal, and to use it in code append _path to the prefix verb. You end up with something like:

```
form_tag calculeaza_path do
```

You may want to read the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), especially the parts about resourceful routes.

Comment: yes that works, I managed to fix it with adding post route in routes.rb. Thank you verry much  post '/calculeaza/' => 'pages#calculeaza'

Answer (score 1):

If you get an error you must include the error message in the question. Anyway the controller name is obviously wrong so this must be the problem. The controller should not include the "/" nor the "_controller".

```
<%= form_tag( { :controller => 'pages', :action => 'calculeaza' }, :method => "post") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :field1 %>
  <%= submit_tag "Button" %>
<% end %>
```

Your routes are also wrong:

- there's no `calculeaza` method in routes
- methods should be lowercase in routes and controller

Thanks to Phlip for the correction about the controller name :)

Comment: I copy paste what you gave me and I recive same error, I added it to the question

Comment: Try `:controller => :pages`. Rails makes a convention that you can leave the redundant word "_controller" out of many situations, beginning with routes.

Comment: still it dose not work: the new error  No route matches {:action=>"calculeaza", :controller=>"pages"}

Comment: If you changed your routes and controller please update the question so we can see the new version